# Linear Regression Loss function for Logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression

I was attending Andrew Ng Machine learning course on youtube Lecture 6.4
He says what a cost function will look like if we used Linear Regression loss function (least squares) for logistic regression
[image: Lecture slide]

I wanted to see such a graph my self and so I tried to plot cost function J with least square loss for a losgistic regression task.

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math


x = np.random.rand(10000)
# x = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4])
y = np.round(np.random.rand(10000))
b = 1

J_list = []
w_list = []
for w in np.arange(-500.5, 500.5, 0.05):
    J = (1/10000)*np.sum((1/2)*np.square(((1/(1 + np.exp(-1*(w*x + b)))) - y)))
    J_list.append(J)
    w_list.append(w)

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['w'] = w_list
df['J'] = J_list

import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x='w', y='J', data=df)
```

The output of lineplot is

[image: cost function with least square loss in logistic regression]

Note: w in my code in theta in Andrew Ng's lecture

If anyone can help me spot my mistake, would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You have taken x,y from random space. So, it should not follow any rule/logic.*

Get a real data *e.g. Iris(just 2 class)* or using *sklearn make_classification* module

 Figure out the approx value of *theta* for a good model

 Then loop before and after this value

 Have *y_true* in probability(*not the Class*)

Comment: Yes you reason is correct. But 'Have y_true in probability(not the Class)' you just meant to convert a Binary label in 0 and 1 right ?

Comment: I meant to use the probability output of the model, not the Class. Till probability calculation only, we have any maths functions involved. So, it will depict the underlying variance accurately. Post that we basically do a  Floor/Ceiling on the output based on a good Thresold e.g. 0.6 --> 1.0. This should be done only at the end.

Comment: yes. The output of the models are in probability only.